# How can I make my navbar responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have this navbar at codepen:http://codepen.io/DogburnDesign/pen/zymID.
It's nice and all but I've realized that it is not responsive. I am quite experienced in making websites but I am new to this responsive thing. Any help guys?

Thanks. here is the code:

## HTML:

```
    <div id="bg"></div>
<section>
  <nav>
    <div></div>
    <ul>
      <li data-xcoord="0px" class="active">Home</li>
      <li data-xcoord="160px">About</li>
      <li data-xcoord="320px">Contact</li>
      <li data-xcoord="480px">Store</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

## CSS:

```
#bg{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
background: #38a8d1;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%, #34bc9a 36%, #34bc9a 57%, #8645f7 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#38a8d1), color-stop(36%,#34bc9a), color-stop(57%,#34bc9a), color-stop(100%,#8645f7));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#38a8d1', endColorstr='#8645f7',GradientType=0 );
}

section{
  position:relative;
  width:640px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
nav{
  width:100%;
}
nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  width:160px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255, 0);
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0;
  margin:-1px -5px -1px -1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:all .2s;
  -webkit-transition:all .2s;
}
nav ul li:hover{
  /*border:1px dashed #fff;*/
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
nav ul{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  z-index:100;
}
nav div{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:16px;
  background: #fff;
  width:162px;
  height:40px;
  z-index:99;
}
.active{
  color:rgba(55, 186, 177, 1);
}
```

## And last but not least, JS:

```
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
  var xcoord = $(this).data("xcoord");

  $("nav div").stop().animate({marginLeft:xcoord}, 500, "easeInOutExpo");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("nav ul li").not(this).removeClass("active");

});
```

Comment: There are various elements of responsive design, perhaps you are interested in resizing the bar appropriately to screen width (google "media query css" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use media queries. **See the working example below** *(You should check the full screen version and play with browser width)*

If you create responsive layouts, it is easier if you think in percentages. You do not create an element that is 640px wide, but you create element that is 100% wide but max-width is 640px. So that if user's viewport is wider than 640px then element is 640px, if viewport is less than 640px wide, then the element is x% of the width. My point is that you need to think responsive, it is not a good practice to create thousands of media queries for every 10px of screen width

I also recommend you to use some responsive css frameworks, i.e 
[Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/)

```js
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
  var xcoord = $(this).data("xcoord");

  $("nav div").stop().animate({marginLeft:xcoord}, 500, "easeInOutExpo");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("nav ul li").not(this).removeClass("active");

});
```

```css
#bg{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
background: #38a8d1;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%, #34bc9a 36%, #34bc9a 57%, #8645f7 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#38a8d1), color-stop(36%,#34bc9a), color-stop(57%,#34bc9a), color-stop(100%,#8645f7));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#38a8d1', endColorstr='#8645f7',GradientType=0 );
}

section{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:640px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
nav{
  width:100%;
}
nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  width:160px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255, 0);
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0;
  margin:-1px -5px -1px -1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:color .2s, background .2s;
  -webkit-transition:color .2s, background .2s;
}
nav ul li:not(.active):hover{
  /*border:1px dashed #fff;*/
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
nav ul{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  z-index:100;
}
.active{
  color:rgba(55, 186, 177, 1);
  background: #fff;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 720px) {
  nav ul{
    width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
  }
  nav ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="bg"></div>
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active">Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Store</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Solution number 2 does not require media queries and keeps list elements floating. **See the solution below**

```js
$("nav ul li").click(function(){
  var xcoord = $(this).data("xcoord");

  $("nav div").stop().animate({marginLeft:xcoord}, 500, "easeInOutExpo");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("nav ul li").not(this).removeClass("active");

});
```

```css
#bg{
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
background: #38a8d1;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%, #34bc9a 36%, #34bc9a 57%, #8645f7 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#38a8d1), color-stop(36%,#34bc9a), color-stop(57%,#34bc9a), color-stop(100%,#8645f7));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #38a8d1 0%,#34bc9a 36%,#34bc9a 57%,#8645f7 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#38a8d1', endColorstr='#8645f7',GradientType=0 );
}

section{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:640px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
nav{
  width:100%;
}
nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255, 0);
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0;
  margin:-1px -5px -1px -1px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:color .2s, background .2s;
  -webkit-transition:color .2s, background .2s;
}
nav ul li:not(.active):hover{
  /*border:1px dashed #fff;*/
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
nav ul{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  z-index:100;
}
.active{
  color:rgba(55, 186, 177, 1);
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg"></div>
<section>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active">Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Store</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: I have a problem with my full site to do with the navbar. On ios and android the scaling is all wrong. Have a look at these screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/OP1uV.  this is the code https://jsfiddle.net/u82ov48c/

Comment: Edit your section element css. Set width: 100%; max-width: 640px.